# are vptr and vtable inherited from base class?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, vtable, vptr, virtual-table

As can be seen, `D3` introduces a new virtual function, `@function3()`, in the middle of the chain of inheritance. I am wondering what is happening with *--vptr and vtable when this happens. D3 is a 'kind of' a new base class now,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void function1() { std::cout << "Base func1()\n"; };
    virtual void function2() { std::cout << "Base func2()\n"; };
};

class D1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void function2() { std::cout << "D1 func2()\n"; };
};

class D2 : public D1 {
public:
    virtual void function1() { std::cout << "D2 func1()\n"; };
};

class D3 : public D2 {
public:
    virtual void function2() { std::cout << "D3 func2()\n"; };
    virtual void function3() { std::cout << "D3 func3()\n"; };
};

class D4 : public D3 {
public:
    virtual void function1() { std::cout << "D4 func1()\n"; };
    virtual void function3() { std::cout << "D4 func3()\n"; };
};

int main() {
    D3 d3;  
}
```

[image: https://imgur.com/a/sxFzrKG]

but when I see vtable entries, what I can see are `function1()`, `function2()`.
I thought entries have to be `function2()`, `function3()`.
Why can't I get what I thought?

Comment: NOTE: vptr/vtable are *implementation details*. Implentations don't *have* to use them to implement virtual dispatch (though most do) - thwy are free to use other methods to achieve the standard mandated behaviour, if they so choose. The compiler is also free to leave out code for stuff it can prove is never actually needed.

Comment: Add code that calls d3.function1(), d3.function2(), and d3.function3(). Check the disassembly. What do you see?

Comment: Possibly the debugger is only showing two entries because `Base` only has two entries.  There will be an additional entry for `function3` that is not shown (or might be below the bottom of the window; check the scroll bar).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Or the compiler just optimized it out since it's never used.

Comment: Unrelated: Once a function is declared `virtual` it's virtual in all derived classes ([But also see `final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)). What this means for you is you don't have to keep repeating `virtual`.

Comment: [override](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) *is* handy to use with those virtual methods in the derived classes, though.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How can (some) virtual functions be optimized out?

Comment: @curiousguy There are situations where the compiler can prove they are never used polymorphically. As an extreme example, consider a `final` class defined in a source file.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How does final "prove" anything?

Comment: @curiousguy It tells the compiler that no other class can inherit from the `final` class. So any `virtual` functions can obviously not be overridden. So the compiler does not need to consider virtual dispatch.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes but then what would would that change for the vptr/vtable themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vtable contains all inherited virtual functions and any newly introduced one.

Here is the vtable for D3 generated by MSVC:

```
const D3::`vftable' DD  FLAT:const D3::`RTTI Complete Object Locator'  ; D3::`vftable'
        DD      FLAT:virtual void D2::function1(void)
        DD      FLAT:virtual void D3::function2(void)
        DD      FLAT:virtual void D3::function3(void)
```

The reason why the debugger doesn't show all of them might be a bug or a limitation.

Comment: could you give me hint how to generate vtable with MSVC ?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean by 'what is happening'. All `vtable`s are specific to class (type). `vtable` for `D1` is different from vtable for `D2`, and so forth.

Vtable for `D3` has more functions in it, than `D1` one. You can normally call those functions if your static type is `D3` or `D4`, but can't call those if your static type is `D1` or `D2`.